# how to get meaningful dependency errors in clojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

If I add the following require:

```
(ns project.core
  (:require
     [compojure.route          :as route])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& {:as args}]
  (println "hello"))
```

an do

```
lein run
```

I get

```
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/ns at (ring/util/mime_type.clj:1:1).
((require [clojure.string :as str])) - failed: Extra input spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-form
```

is there a way I can get
"compojure.route not found; not defined; or whatever" e.g. something meaningful?
if I remove it it works fine. e.g. it says Hello

using Leiningen 2.9.4 on Java 14.0.1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you are using is using very old dependencies.  Clojure spec (introduced "recenlty") added macro/compile time checks and the mentioned file there triggers it.

`compojure.route` actually is found and it then requires its transitive deps.  And while going down the chain `ring.util.mime-type` is required and the version you are using is not ready for current Clojure versions.

Your best bet here is to upgrade your deps.  E.g. if you are following a book or if you are using a template this things can happen.  If you have `lein-ancient` installed, it can attempt the update for you.  Otherwise your best bet is to start in your `project.clj` and compare versions (e.g. check clojars).

If the problem still persists, have a look at `lein deps :tree` and see what is going on with the transtive deps.

Comment: For the record: it was fixed six years ago: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/commit/a05e026d85611cb179a1352d569d7c68713f792c

Comment: Thanks for the explanation lein deps: tree showed where the old dependency was